# Google Cloud Computing Datastore

Tags: node.js, express, google-cloud-datastore

Problem: Query Filter (string) does not always yield the correct results.
e.g.

1. String "/blog" result found
2. String "/blog/how-to-choose-the-right-content-management-system" does not yield a result
3. String "/blog/how-to-find-the-right-domain-name-for-your-product-or-service" yields a result but the other indexed column is inaccesible in node.js

I've tested directly on GCP interface (entity filters) and the results are consistent with what I am getting in Node.js.

Should I be storing URLs as string or should I be encoding it in base64 to get an exact match?

Comment: Do you have some code?

Comment: The following code is a simplified version. For simplicity reasons I have excluded other parts of it.

var query = getPages('Estevo','Page', 'URI', '/');
datastoreClient.runQuery(query, function(err, entities) {
res.render(layout, {  page: entities[0] });
});

Comment: Dear All, I found the problem that is causing one entity not to be found. Apparently there seems to a be space at the end of the string. Now I am working on the node portion with regards to the indexing error. Thank you.

Comment: Dear All, I deleted the variable names in pug template and just wrote the names again and the sub pages are now working. At the moment I can't explain why. I hope it is not due to the captalisation i.e. cos the entitity names have the first letter capitalised - based on Google's example. Hence I am using in pug variables like page.Title . I hope it is a one of problem. Thank you